# Как в Python ввести в массив n элементов в одну строку

Tags: python, массивы

есть входные данные
**a, b, c, d = map(int,input().split()**
есть 3 массива **B, G** и **R**, в каждый из которых необходимо ввести числа, количество которых равно **a, b, c** соответственно.
нужно найти по 1 элементу из каждого массива что бы
**B[i]^2 + G[i]^2 + R[i]^2 = d**
при этом эти числа были разными.
помогите реализовать

Comment: Не понятен вопрос, опишите подробнее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = 3
s = input().split(maxsplit = a)
B = list(map(int, s))
```

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понял вопрос...
Можно разбить строку целиком, а потом взять нужное количество элементов в каждый список.

```
a, b = 3, 5
tmp = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0'.split()
B, G = tmp[:a], tmp[a:a+b]
print(f"B = {B}    G = {G}")
```

А можно так:

```
a, b = 3, 5
B = '1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0'.split(maxsplit=a)
B, G = B[:-1], B[-1].split(maxsplit=b)[:-1]
print(f"B = {B}    G = {G}")
```

```
B = ['1', '2', '3']    G = ['4', '5', '6', '7', '8']
```